# SQL GROUP rows by day then groups in DESC (Still need help)

Tags: php, sql, group-by

Right now i'm just ordering all the rows by DESC, but i want to put the rows that are created the same day into groups and the groups in DESC.

This is what i currenly have:

```
$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM test3 WHERE aktiv LIKE 'Ja' ORDER BY date DESC ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);
```

This is my table:
[image]

So it will echo out all the rows that where created on 17 first then 16 and 14 into groups, then i can echo out the date of the different groups. So do i need to use GROUP BY or first find the dates then put it into groups.

I have tried different ways of doing it, but its so many different answers around and can't find the right solution for me, so i need a bit of help.

Comment: I don't understand what result set you want.  Ordering by the date with the time also orders by the date.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That is just what i have now, but i want to group the rows by the date then order the groups by DESC. I want to do this so i can target the different groups.

Comment: You need to group by the "date" part of date, ie _without_ the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use aggregation function min for id and date for datetime to date

```
 SELECT date(date) as day,aktiv,betvalue,min(id)
 FROM test3 WHERE aktiv LIKE 'Ja'  group by day,aktiv,betvalue
 ORDER BY date(date) DESC
```

Comment: That is doing the exact same thing as before, i want to put the different rows in to groups that can be echoed out and each group can be called by the date.

Comment: @Seb share your expected output